# Unable to log in to a Ubuntu remote server from a Mac client using VNC after screen lock

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, vnc, x11vnc

I can log in and use a remote Ubuntu-20.04 server from my MacOS-13 client. If the screen is left idle for X mins, it locks itself up.

However, I am unable to log in back into the same session and the screen freezes at the locked page.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Another problem is the sockets (I am not sure if they are called that, but it's the number after colon (:X) in vncserver) that are once locked aren't able to be used again event after killing the process and deleting the pid files from .vnc/.